# Can't use "num_to_well" function Package platetools

Tags: r

I am trying to use the function "num_to_well" from the package "platetools" and I keep getting an error **"could not find function "num_to_well"** (it happens both in R and R studio)

I am using Rstudio Version 1.3.959

I am using R Version 4.0.2

I already uninstalled the package and re-installed again with no success. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you positive you successfully loaded the package after you installed it using the code `library(platetools)`?

Comment: Thank you so much! Problem solved!